# Created node doesn't have attachEvent property

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In my js application where required js is used I'be got an error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Script error for: ModuleName
```

I made an investigation and find out that `require.js` core file in the function `req.load` is trying to create node `document.createElement('script')` and then checks if this node has `attachEvent` property. In my case it's script node. And there is no `attachEvent` property. By this reason I've got an error.
Can somebody explain why it happens?

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: You are probably using quiet old version. I am using RequireJS 2.3.6 and it has support for both attachEvent and addEventListener. It checks which method is supoorted by the browser before calling